# Java, Access a Deque stored in a list

Tags: java, deque, unsafe, unchecked

So I have this list `l1` of Deques, stored with ListArray,
Strings are stored in the Deques.

1. When I try to poll the String from one of the Deque, I got this error:
   error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
   `temp = l1.get(b).pollFirst();`

But `l1.get(b).pollFirst().getClass().getName()` returns java.lang.String

I resolved it by changing the line into `temp = (String)l1.get(b).pollFirst();`  But not sure why and if it's the correct way.

2. When I try to access enqueue this String `temp` to another Deque in the list, with `l1.get(a).offerLast(temp);`, I got `uses unchecked or unsafe operations.`

How should I fix this issue??

The code piece is as follows:

```
while (!l1.get(b).isEmpty()){
    temp = l1.get(b).pollFirst();
    l1.get(a).offerLast(temp);
}
```

Comment: Could you edit the question and show how are the list and deques declared?

Comment: (always use human-readable variable-names .... very hard to read with such generic abbrevations)

Comment: seems to me you've not specified type parameter for the Deque during decalaration

Comment: @Liquidpie Thx! That's exactly the problem! thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the required type parameter for the `Deque` stored in your list. The correct declaration would look like:

```
List<Deque<String>> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also, as mentioned in comments, do think more about variable names, "l1" gives the reader no idea what this list is for.

Comment: When you find an answer useful @Vera, you can upvote it, and mark it as "the" accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the problem is parameterized types don't have type parameter specified. Once you specify the same, you don't have to do type casting for `temp`. Following example code help you to understand this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class DequeExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DequeExample dequeExample = new DequeExample();
        dequeExample.testDeque();
    }

    public void testDeque() {
        List<Deque<String>> deques = prepareDeques();
        int indexOfDequeA = 0;
        int indexOfDequeB = 1;
        while (!deques.get(indexOfDequeB).isEmpty()){
            String temp = deques.get(indexOfDequeB).pollFirst();
            deques.get(indexOfDequeA).offerLast(temp);
        }
        System.out.println("Modified Deque A = " + deques.get(indexOfDequeA));
        System.out.println("Modified Deque B = " + deques.get(indexOfDequeB));
    }

    private List<Deque<String>> prepareDeques() {
        List<Deque<String>> deques = new ArrayList<>();
        Deque<String> dequeB = new LinkedList<>();
        deques.add(dequeB);
        Deque<String> dequeA = new LinkedList<>();
        deques.add(dequeA);
        dequeB.addLast("Element1");
        dequeB.addLast("Element2");
        dequeB.addLast("Element3");
        System.out.println("Initial Deque A = " + dequeA);
        System.out.println("Initial Deque B = " + dequeB);
        return deques;
    }
}
```